# how to handle multiple form submits in django

Tags: django, django-views

So I have a page in django where I can click a button to add multiple lines of a form, all inside one . Like if i wanted to add a lot of people all at once. When the form submits it only adds one of the instances. I am trying to find a way to process all of the forms. They are all for the same model. I found this example which seems to be close to what I am looking for, however in my case there is a variable number of forms. does anyone know a way to implement something like that?

```
if request.POST():
a_valid = formA.is_valid()
b_valid = formB.is_valid()
c_valid = formC.is_valid()
# we do this since 'and' short circuits and we want to check to whole page for form     errors
if a_valid and b_valid and c_valid:
    a = formA.save()
    b = formB.save(commit=False)
    c = formC.save(commit=False)
    b.foreignkeytoA = a
    b.save()
    c.foreignkeytoB = b
    c.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets) are for.